# Classic ASP - CINT error with missing request

Tags: asp-classic, request

I have a Type mismatch error with CINT.

This happens when I compare : CINT(BOX1) = CINT(BOX2) and BOX1 was missing in the request.

If I got : http://www.exemple.com/test.asp?BOX1=

(and made a BOX1 = REQUEST("BOX1"))

The CINT(BOX1) type mismatch error happens.

There is a way to treat this error?

(IsNull doesn't work - BOX1 isn't null)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I treat the error using ISNUMERIC function. Is not the best solution (because this create another IF clauses) but is a good solution.

```
**IF ISNUMERIC(BOX1) THEN...**
```